# How to convert values in string into System.Windows.Point in C#?

Tags: c#, string, points

I am using C# and I have a string with the values like strResult = "(30,40),(189,339),(30,40),(60,30)". I wanted to convert these value into **System.Windows.Point** .
so that 1st value of point[0].x = 30 ,point[0].y = 40 and so on.

```
{
 string[] numbers = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(strResult, @"[(),]+");
  for (int i = 0; i < numbers; i++)
  { 
   System.Windows.Point point = // do something
   drawingContext.DrawEllipse(Brushes.Green, null, new System.Windows.Point(point.X, point.Y), 3, 3);
  }
```

Can anyone help on this ?  Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a more appropriate regex expression for your scenario: `\((.*?)\)`

This will provide you with an array of all the points as `x, y`. Now you just have to split the string by `,` and trim the results. Finally, loop through the point array and create a new point with parsed int values.

```
    var pointString = "(30,40),(189,339),(30,40),(60,30)";
    var ps = Regex.Split(pointString, @"\((.*?)\)");
    foreach (var p in ps) {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(p)) {
            var px = p.Split(',');
            var x = int.Parse(px[0].Trim());
            var y = int.Parse(px[1].Trim());
            var point = new Point(x, y);
            Console.WriteLine(point);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Parsing strings into ints can be done with `Convert.ToInt32` or `Int32.Parse` (or many other options).

Be careful with your regex. That particular code will return array with empty first and last elements: `"", "30", "40", ..., "60", "30", ""` .

You can parse 2 elements for single point in each iteration. I handled first and last empty elements but it would be better to rewrite regex properly:

```
    for (int i = 1; i < numbers.Length - 1; i += 2)
    {       
       System.Windows.Point point = new System.Windows.Point(Convert.ToInt32(numbers[i]), Convert.ToInt32(numbers[i + 1])); 
       drawingContext.DrawEllipse(Brushes.Green, null, new System.Windows.Point(point.X, point.Y), 3, 3);
    }
```